# How to download file Type XLSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have file in assets
[image: Path to the asset]
and i hope this file can download in my project

```
<button className='p-2 bg-green-600 my-3 text-white '>
    <href='../../../Assets/file/form_upload_lead.xlsx'>Download Format Upload</a>
</button>
```

[image: module not found]

i hope this file can download. when i download this file the result like this
[image: Error on download]

Comment: What is the file tree of your project?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is meant to be public it should be stored on the `public` folder or a subdirectory of it.

- You will typically place the `Assets` folder on `public` folder
- Then You can (access) download the file in the path `/Assets/file/form_upload_lead.xlsx`

After that clicking directly to the link will trigger the download of the file:

```
 <button className='p-2 bg-green-600 my-3 text-white '>
   <a href='/Assets/file/form_upload_lead.xlsx'>Download Format Upload</a>
 </button>
```